# Fill Datagridview in each new identical TabPages

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, datagridview, tabcontrol, tabpage

I have TabControl with 1 TabPages and contains DataGridView.
I create TabPages2 from TabPages1 with code :

```
    Dim Frm As New TabFormPage
    Dim MoreTabs As TabPage = Frm.TabPage1
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To TabControl1.TabPages.Count
        MoreTabs.Text = "TabPage" & i + 1
    Next i
    TabControl1.Controls.Add(MoreTabs)
    Frm.Dispose()
```

TabPages2 Controls identical to TabPages1

If I fill DataGridView with BackgroundWorker in TabPages1 , it was working . But if I fill DataGridView in every New TabPages ( eg TabPages2 ) from different sources , it was not working (DataGridView in TabPages2/each New TabPages is empty/nothing) . It always fills Tabpages1 DataGridView

How to fill every DataGridView in every New TabPages with identical controls ?
Here's my code to fill DataGridview :

```
    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
        MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + FPathTab + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
        MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" & CSheetTab1 & "]'", MyConnection)

        DtSet = New System.Data.DataSet
        DtSet.Clear()
        MyCommand.Fill(DtSet)
    End Sub
    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
        DataGridView1.DataSource = DtSet.Tables(0)
        dv = DtSet.Tables(0).DefaultView
        MaxRecords = DtSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count
        MyConnection.Close()
        DataGridView1.Columns("F20").Visible = False
        DataGridView1.Columns("F21").Visible = False
        DataGridView1.Columns("F22").Visible = False
    End Sub
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you trying to accomplish something like this: [Using one datagridview across multiple tabs in tabcontrol](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20663578/using-one-datagridview-across-multiple-tabs-in-tabcontrol)?

Comment: Yes, something like that

Comment: But, It was not working  with my code duplicating identical New TabPages
in first code post above

Comment: This will *not* create a new tab page: `Dim MoreTabs As TabPage = Frm.TabPage1` (Unless TabPage1 is a function returning a new instance of a tab page) TabPage is a reference type, not a value type. You need to create a new control using the `new` keyword: `New TabPage()`,

Comment: That worked , but why datagridview in TabPage1 also filled ?
I need to fill every DataGridView in every TabPages with different data (not the same data)